# Choose between two values of a column where the values in other columns of the table are same

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

**I have a table as below:**

[image]

The `Case_ID` `111` has two records.
How do I write a query to choose the row for `Case_ID` `111`, where the `Result` is `Passed` ?

Also, `Case_ID` `113` has only 1 row, and it has the `Result` of `Failed`.
How do I get that row?

**The result table is as below:**

[image]

Comment: I have tried: select distinct e.* from Test_results e where  (e.Result='Passed' or e.Result='Failed' and exists (
            select 1 from Test_results e1 where e1.case_id = e.case_id and e1.Result='Passed' ))order by Case_ID

Comment: And the result am getting is:  Case_id 111 with result as pass and Case_id 222 but am not getting the row with case_id 113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can aggregate by case ID/name and script name, and then select the maximum value of the `Result` column.  For those cases/scripts which passed, the max value would be `Passed`, while for the case of a single failure, `Failed` would be reported.

```
SELECT
    Case_ID,
    Case_Name,
    Script_Name,
    MAX(Result) AS Result
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Case_ID,
    Case_Name,
    Script_Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the query below with fiddle ..

```
SELECT Case_id,Case_Name,Script_Name,max(result) Result
FROM dbo.abc
GROUP BY Case_id,Case_Name,Script_Name
```

Please check link here [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ae19d9/2/0)

[image: click here to check]

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement an order for pass fail

```
SELECT
    Case_ID,
    Case_Name,
    Script_Name,
    Result
FROM (SELECT
      Case_ID,
      Case_Name,
      Script_Name,
      Result,
      ROW_Number() OVER(Partition BY Case_ID ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN Result = 'Passed' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS ResultNo
      FROM yourTable)
WHERE ResultNo =1
```